# Link and get specific data from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, links

So I have a workbook named `dwg data.xls` that contains a table with the following columns:

```
DWG No | S1 | S2
```

And I have another workbook named `report template.xls` that contains a report template.

In the template I have three cells. In one cell I have to enter DWG No. As soon as I enter the DWG no, the current workbook should search for the entered dwg no in the dwg no. column of the `dwg data.xls` workbook  and automatically fill the corresponding S1 and S2 values in dedicated cells of the `report template.xls`. How can I achieve this?

Optional:
As an optional, It would be nice if- as I enter the dwg no in the dedicated cell of  `report template.xls` a combobox or something similar should display all the similar values from dwg no column of the `dwg data.xls` workbook and be able to select a value from the combobox.

**I prefer not to use vba for this.**

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your post with screenshots of sample data and how you expect your result to show. Please also add details of what you've tried so far.

Comment: This sounds like a simple lookup task to be done with something like INDEX and MATCH, or even VLOOKUP since the parameters seem relatively fixed. What have you tried already?

Comment: Now I using VLOOKUP abd its working well. I wasn't aware of that function while I was posting the question.